# WIX: Change value of Bundle Level Variable from Chain msi(s)

Tags: wix

I have a bundle declared which installs 3 applications one after another.

1)Database   2)Web Services 3)Web Application

In the step 1 - 
I am calling an MSI which installs database from scripts.Here I have taken Server, Database Name, User Name and Password.

I want to carry forward these details to STEP 3 (which will be called after step 2)i.e MSI 3 which is a part of bundle.

My questions are --

How I can set the Bundle level Variable PASSED_DATABASE in STEP1 ?

How I can access it in Step3 ?

```
<Bundle>    
 <Variable Name="PASSED_DATABASE" Type="string"  bal:Overridable="yes" Value="DefaultDatabase" />
    <Chain>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="myApp.Database"></PackageGroupRef>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="myApp.Service"></PackageGroupRef>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="myApp.ApplicationName"></PackageGroupRef>        
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
```

```
<PackageGroup Id="myApp.Database">
  <MsiPackage
    Id="myApp.Database"
    DisplayName="myApp - Database"
    DisplayInternalUI="yes"
    Visible="yes"
    EnableFeatureSelection="yes"
    SourceFile="$(var.myAppDB.Installer.TargetDir)\myAPPDB.msi">
    <MsiProperty Name="PASSED_DATABASE" Value="[PASSED_DATABASE]"/>
  </MsiPackage>
</PackageGroup>

<PackageGroup Id="myApp.Service">
  <MsiPackage
    Id="myApp.Service"
    DisplayName="myApp Service"
    DisplayInternalUI="yes"
    Visible="yes"
    EnableFeatureSelection="yes"
    SourceFile="$(var.myApp.Service.TargetDir)\myApp.Service.msi">
    <MsiProperty Name="PASSED_DATABASE" Value="[PASSED_DATABASE]"/>
  </MsiPackage>
</PackageGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an option of storing the details in Registry and access it through out the bundle.
This worked well in my case.